# Magento 2 Enable maintenance mode except my ip

Tags: magento2, command-line, maintenance

I want to enable maintenance mode except my ip address, and I have run below command in CLI tool

```
php bin/magento maintenance:enable --ip= 180.233.1--.1-- (this is my ip)
```

this enables the maintenance mode including my system, while I have already excluded my ip.

I don't know why this is not working correctly.

If anyone have idea please let me know.

Comment: Do you have varnish or Cloudflare configured

Comment: @RajMohanR ,no such services are configured.

Comment: Can you please check in your var directory for maintenance files and for the allowed IP in that file

Answer (score 1):

Enable maintenance mode except Your IP

> bin/magento maintenance:enable
>
> bin/magento maintenance:allow-ips **your ip**

Answer (score 0):

You can `enable disable maintenance mode` and `exempt IP-addresses enable disable` for using below command.

**Maintenance mode Enable:**

> php bin/magento maintenance:enable

**Maintenance mode Disable:**

> php bin/magento maintenance:disable

**Maintenance mode Enable List of exempt IP-addresses**

> php bin/magento maintenance:enable --ip=192.0.3.26 --ip=192.0.4.27

**Maintenance mode remove List of exempt IP-addresses**

> php bin/magento maintenance:disable --ip=none

Hope it help!

Comment: I am doing in same way but it is not working.

Comment: Is this your IP address 180.233.1 ?

Comment: my ip something like this 80.233.1--.1--

Comment: What about -- – ?

Comment: these are number of my ip,I don't want to disclose full IP

Comment: Just run command php bin/magento maintenance:enable --ip=yourip
and let me know the output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96303/discussion-between-kirti-nariya-and-akgola).

Answer (score 0):

php bin/magento maintenance:enable --ip 192.0.3.26 --ip 192.0.4.27